# How does JPA EntityManager determines if an entity already exists?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have `EntityManager em` and that I have `Entity e`.  When I call `em.persist(e)` the Java EE JPA documentation says that an EntityExistsException is thrown if `e` already exists in the persistence context.

Now, suppose that entities of type `Entity` have a surrogate key generated automatically by the database, but they also have a field (or fields) with uniqueness constraints that make any entity of type `Entity` unique.

How does `EntityManager em` determines that the new element I am trying to insert to the database already exists there? Is it from the `equals` method defined in `Entity`, or is it by attempting to insert to the database and getting back an error because some uniqueness constraints were violated? (Obviously, I think it shouldn't be because the surrogate primary key of the object I am inserting is equal to the surrogate primary key of an object in the database, since the surrogate primary key of the object I am inserting is null (or my thinking is wrong here?)).  If it is the latter, how am I sure that the `persist` is throwing an `EntityExistsException` instead of a `PersistenceException`?

Comment: if something has a "surrogate key" then it will have a field for that key, and it can easily do a "SELECT blah FROM tbl WHERE key = value". Looking at the log would tell you what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way than doing an `INSERT` and catching a database exception. Any other ways are unreliable since databases are multi-user environments.

For example, oracle throws a "unique constraint violated" and it shows which 
constraints were violated.

```
QL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.CONSTRAINT_NAME) violated
```